# Integration and recurrence relation problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

I have the following integral,
$$
I(\alpha) = \int_a^b x^{\alpha} f(x) dx
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)$ is a function which has derivatives up to order $k$, e.g. $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for $n > k$. Assume I know the value of $f$ and all its derivatives at the points $a$ and $b$.

Now, suppose I know the value of $I(\alpha)$. I would like to find $I(\alpha + 1)$ in terms of $I(\alpha)$ if possible. In other words I want to find a recurrence relation. I tried an integration by parts approach:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha + 1) &= \int_a^b x^{\alpha+1} f(x) dx \\
&= \int_a^b x x^{\alpha} f(x) dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left. x^{\alpha + 2} f(x) \right|_a^b - \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b x^2 \left( \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} f(x) + x^{\alpha} f'(x) \right) dx \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \left. x^{\alpha + 2} f(x) \right|_a^b - \frac{\alpha}{2} I(\alpha + 1) -\frac{1}{2} \int_a^b x^{\alpha + 2} f'(x) dx
\end{align}
Now I could continue doing integration by parts until I reach $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ but the expression gets quite messy and I am wondering if there may be a better way to proceed.

Can anyone see a more elegant way to calculate $I(\alpha + 1)$ in terms of $I(\alpha)$?

Comment: I would use integration by parts for $\alpha\neq -1$ in this way $$\int\limits_a^bx^\alpha f(x)\,dx = {1\over \alpha +1}x^{\alpha +1}f(x)  \bigr\vert_a^b-{1\over \alpha+1}\int\limits_a^bx^{\alpha+1}f'(x)\,dx$$ For $\alpha=-1$ we get
$$\int\limits_a^bx^{-1} f(x)\,dx = \log x \,f(x)  \bigr\vert_a^b-\int\limits_a^b\log x\,f'(x)\,dx$$ I guess you assume $b>a>0.$

Comment: Thanks, this is a better approach, and it also shows that there is no clear way to make a recurrence relation